# Why are for loops quicker than numpy for 2D array multiplication

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy

Consider the following two functions, which essentially multiply every number in a small sequence with every number in a larger sequence to build up a 2D array, and then doubles all the values in the array. `noloop()` uses direct multiplication of 2D numpy arrays and returns the result, whereas `loop()` uses a for loop to iterate over `arr1` and gradually build up an output array.

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.random.rand(100, 1)
arr2 = np.random.rand(1, 100000)

def noloop():
    return (arr1*arr2)*2

def loop():
    out = np.empty((arr1.size, arr2.size))
    for i in range(arr1.size):
        tmp = (arr1[i]*arr2)*2
        out[i] = tmp.reshape(tmp.size)
    return out
```

I expected `noloop` to be much faster even for a small number of iterations, but for the array sizes above, `loop` is actually faster:

```
>>> %timeit noloop()
10 loops, best of 3: 64.7 ms per loop
>>> %timeit loop()
10 loops, best of 3: 41.6 ms per loop
```

And interestingly, if I remove `*2` in both functions, `noloop` is faster, but only slightly:

```
>>> %timeit noloop()
10 loops, best of 3: 29.4 ms per loop
>>> %timeit loop()
10 loops, best of 3: 34.4 ms per loop
```

Is there a good explanation for these results, and is there a notably faster way to perform the same task?

Comment: I get `noloop()` being faster (by ~15%) than `loop()` regardless...

Comment: I also get the reverse on both python2 and python3.

Comment: I get `loop` being faster, as OP suggests (by 28% in my machine). Python 3.4.1 | Anaconda 2.1.0, IPython 2.2.0

Comment: The OP values are from Spyder, i.e. a QT IPython console. I get the same results using a QT IPython console outside of Spyder. Strangely, it seems that in a normal IPython console, `noloop()` takes just as long as before (60-70 ms), while `loop()` takes a few ms longer than `noloop()`, i.e. significantly slower than in the QT console.

Comment: Same here, `noloop()` is ~10% faster on my machine.

Comment: I get similar results on my machine (retina iMac, OS X 10.10, framework Python 2.7.9 or 3.4.2, numpy 1.9.1 -- pure bumpy (no explicit "out") about 75% slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce your results, but I did find that I could get substantial speed up (factor of 2) using `numpy.multiply`. By using the `out` argument you can take advantage of the fact that the memory is already allocated and eliminate the copying of `tmp` to `out`.

```
def out_loop():
    out = np.empty((arr1.size, arr2.size))
    for i in range(arr1.size):
        np.multiply(arr1[i], arr2, out=out[i].reshape((1, arr2.size)))
        out[i] *= 2
    return out
```

Results on my machine:

```
In [32]: %timeit out_loop()
100 loops, best of 3: 17.7 ms per loop

In [33]: %timeit loop()
10 loops, best of 3: 28.3 ms per loop
```